# Subnet With Two IPv6 Routers / How To Get Default Route Correct?

Tags: ipv6

I am trying to create a subnet with two IPv6 routers, call them R1 and R2. Originally, my subnet had only R1, connecting it to the Internet via a Hurricane Electric tunnel. R1 was (and still is) running radvd, and all hosts on the subnet are working fine (and still are, so I won't post R1's radvd.conf here). Recently, I added R2 to the subnet, and put another (new) subnet behind it. I have radvd running on R2, with the following radvd.conf file:

```
interface eth2 {
  AdvSendAdvert on;
  MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
  MaxRtrAdvInterval 10;
  prefix 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 {
    AdvOnLink on;
    AdvAutonomous on;
  };
};
interface eth0 {
  AdvSendAdvert on;
  MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
  MaxRtrAdvInterval 10;
  prefix 2001:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/64 {
    AdvAutonomous off;
    AdvOnLink off;
  };
  route 2001:470:291c:0002::/64 {};
};
```

Where eth0 is connected to the original subnet, and eth2 is connected to the new subnet.

**Here's the problem**: The RAs from R2 are overriding the default route on all the hosts on the original subnet (so that they no longer have the correct default route, as advertised by R1). R2's default route still correctly points at R1, so everything on the subnet "works", in that external IPv6 nodes are reachable, but all external traffic is now incorrectly getting routed through R2.

**So my question is**: how can I prevent the RAs from R2 from setting the default route for hosts on my original subnet (the one with both R1 and R2 connected to it)? I need the RAs from R1 to provide that default route!

Many thanks, in advance. This is my first post to *Stack Overflow*, so let me know if I did something wrong!

Comment: Interesting question, I think you might have better luck on https://serverfault.com/ or maybe  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ Good luck!

Comment: This question is off-topic here, but very short hint: think about why you're sending RAs on eth0 at all. For more info, please ask this on networkengineering if this is a professionally managed network or on superuser if it's a home network.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why this is off topic, but I can ask this question at those other places too. The reason that I want to send RAs out eth0 is that I want hosts on my 'original' subnet to be able to access hosts on my 'new' subnet. I don't see how my 'original' hosts will get a route to my 'new' hosts without those RAs going out eth0.